# How to get the index of the first non-zero value for a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the index of the first non-zero value for a specific column of a pandas dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[0,0,0],
    [0,0,3],
    [1,5,7],
    [8,7,3]],
    columns=['c1','c2','c3'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    c1  c2  c3
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   3
2   1   5   7
3   8   7   3
```

I would like to get an index position of value 5 (first non zero value) in column c2.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander you have to be sure there is at least one matching value ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) combined with [`first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html):

```
df.loc[df['c2'].ne(0), 'c2'].first_valid_index()
```

output: `2`

*NB. if there was only zeros in the column, the output would be `None`.*

Comment: @AnoushiravanR `idxmax` would give an incorrect answer on a column of only zeros